# How do I inspect network traffic on a react native app on iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, networking, react-native

I'm using the latest React Native (0.18 at the time of this writing) and would like to inspect the network requests my iOS simulator makes.
Using the latest Xcode "instruments" i get this: [image] . I get the same error on both 10.11 and 10.10 machines, both using the latest Xcode.

I've also tried using Charles, but it's unable to intercept the traffic.
Wireshark is able to see it, but the data I'm after is SSL based, so I cannot access it.

As a webdeveloper, ideally I'd like to inspect network traffic in my chrome debugger, but I understand that this cannot be possible in this kind of environment, but simply looking at raw packet data is not userfriendly enough for debugging purposes.

Who knows of a solution for this?

Comment: Charles Proxy should work and will decrypt the SSL traffic unless the certificate is pinned. I use Charles all the time.

Comment: @zaph: can you please describe how you set up Charles in conjunction with the iOS simulator?

Comment: Help > SSL Proxying > Install Charles Root Certificate in iOS Simulators)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out using Charles is a good option.

Just set up the SSL certificates:
Help > SSL Proxying > Install Charles Root Certificate in iOS Simulators) in charles and be happy!

Comment: I can't get Charles Proxy to work even without SSL. I can't get the websockets debugger to work on my mobile device? Otherwise it does download the code from my computer using Charles Proxy. I don't suppose you have an idea of how to get this setup?

Comment: Same for me, I can't get Charles to show the request, even though I'm making the request to my localhost, no SSL.

Comment: @alexmngn did you ever find a solution? ...the main thing I'm trying to solve is to make it so all members of my team can use the same code without having to change IP addresses. In the objective C delegate and websockets file, etc, i specify a domain name (rather than an ip address or local host), which developers can locally redirect to 127.0.0.1 via their /etc/hosts file. Then all they have to do is get charles proxy working properly for their iPhone. Basic HTTP traffic works, but  the following URL seems to fail over websockets: my.domain.com:8081/debugger-proxy?role=client

Answer (score 1):

I might be a little bit late but as I was searching on this topic I found this https://github.com/infinitered/reactotron tool very helpful, this not only displays the network traffic but also displays the errors in the application and state also

Answer (score -1):

Actually, now you can view network traffic using the react native network inspector introduced in version 0.33. I demo how to use the inspector in my video on how to make network requests in react native (starting at 1:46) http://codecookbook.co/post/how-to-make-network-requests-in-react-native/