# Ignore self-signed SSL certificate in fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, fetch

I'm using `fetch` in a react-native app, and charles proxy to debug my network requests.  In order to use charles with SSL, I need to configure fetch to accept a self-signed certificate generated by charles.

How do I tell fetch to ignore errors from self-signed certificates when using https?

Comment: visit the url in your browser and accept the warnings. then ajax will work.

Comment: no dice.  The url works fine in chrome, but the chrome dev tools show that the request is being rejected.  Charles says that the remote host closed the connection during ssl handshake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by setting up the SSL certificates in the simulator: Help > SSL Proxying > Install Charles Root Certificate in iOS Simulators) in charles and be happy!

Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/a/35047215/82156