# Error while using fetch in react native app

Tags: ios, react-native, fetch

I am using the following fetch call in a react native app:

```
fetch(apiUrls.signInUrl, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    user: {
      email: username,
      password: password,
    }
  })
})
.then(response => {
  response.json().then(responseJson => {
    dispatch(AccountActions.loginResponse(username, password, responseJson.token, response.status));
    dispatch(CardActions.getCards(username, responseJson.token));
  });
})
.catch(err => {
  console.error(err);
});
```

The fetch call is failing with the following error screen. Any help?
[image]

Comment: Have you tried using a proxy like Charles to inspect network traffic? http://stackoverflow.com/a/35047215/869895

Comment: 1 - Can you access the internet from safari on the simulator/phone?
2 - is the internet working on your computer? 
3 - Is your internet working at all?

Comment: internet is working. other api calls in the same app are working fine. even the same api call, if I press the login button again, it works fine.

Comment: After I installed Charles root certificate in iOS simulator, it seems to be working fine. The first call was always the one giving me the problem. Even that seems to be resolved now. I am going to close this question. @alexp, Thanks for Charles proxy suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IOS http connections are disabled by default. So you would have to enable it. Though it isn't recommended, it should be fine for debug mode.

Here are the steps:
1. You go to Info.plist file of your iOS project in Xcode

2. Change allow Arbitrary loads to "YES"
   [image]
3. Optionally you can also add your trusted host to exception domains if you don't like to enable "allow arbitrary loads" option

Good luck!